# Apply bicubic scaling filter to a Pixi.js sprite

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, pixi.js

I am using the WebGL based framework [Pixi.js](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/) for a game and I try to apply a bicubic scaling filter. The performance isn't important in this case.

Here you can see an example made with CSS:

[image: Example]

Please check my Chrome optimized [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ymkst/16/).

This code is for a linear scaled image:

```
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF, true);
var bg = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("image.png");
bg.scale.x = .125;
bg.scale.y = .25;
stage.addChild(bg);

var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(93, 79);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);
var textureHasLoaded = false;
checkIfTextureHasLoaded();

function checkIfTextureHasLoaded(){
    if (bg.texture.baseTexture.hasLoaded){
        textureHasLoaded = true;
        renderTexture();   
    }
    if (!textureHasLoaded){
        requestAnimFrame(checkIfTextureHasLoaded);
    }
}

function renderTexture(){
    renderer.render(stage);   
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Pixi.js versions 3.0 and above default scaling can be set by changing PIXI.SCALE_MODES.DEFAULT:

```
PIXI.SCALE_MODES.DEFAULT = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST;
```

For Pixi.js versions 1.5.0 and above the constants have been [moved](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/commit/b0f8c931b0cd865b0649aad59d0fab00fce7a337) and scaling is now set as:

```
PIXI.scaleModes.DEFAULT = PIXI.scaleModes.NEAREST;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Pixi.js team will add the possibility to specify [scaling filters](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/201) soon.

**Edit:**

You are now able to [specify the default scale mode](https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/pull/378):

```
PIXI.Texture.SCALE_MODE.DEFAULT = PIXI.Texture.SCALE_MODE.NEAREST;
```

Comment: This is now `PIXI.settings.SCALE_MODE = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST` or `texture.scaleMode = PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST`